# Convert string to spinal case

Tags: javascript, strings, regex

Due to an excercise, I've made a function that converts given string to spinal case `just-like-this-one` (all lower case).
I did it with two regular expressions. Can it be done with one, or generally better?

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
  //if string is not delimited 
  if(str.search(/[_\s]/) === -1){
    // insert dash before every uppercase letter
    return str.replace(/(?=[A-Z])/g , '-').toLowerCase();
  } else {    
    //change delimiters to dashes  
    return str.replace(/[_\s](?=[a-zA-Z])/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

edit:
variable naming was forced by excercise (wouldn't complete otherwise).
Example converted input:

"This Is Spinal Tap"

"thisIsSpinalTap"

"The_Andy_Griffith_Show"

"Teletubbies say Eh-oh"

Answer (score 3):

This does it in two steps:

1. Add spaces before each uppercase, which allows the uppercases to be handled by...
2. The delimiter case.  This is the same regex you already wrote, although I am collapsing multiple delimters down to a single one.

Having two transformation passes, similar to using a unix pipeline, is easier to reason about that breaking it up into two cases with an "if else".

Note the cryptic `(?!^)` matches "*not* at the beginning of a line" only

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?!^)([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
            .replace(/[_\s]+(?=[a-zA-Z])/g, '-').toLowerCase();
}
```

All of your test cases pass:

```
this-is-spinal-tap
this-is-spinal-tap
the-andy-griffith-show
teletubbies-say-eh-oh
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, to start, you have 3 regexes and duplicate code. `str`, while it is implied as a string, should be named to something that it is, like `stringToConvert`.

Now you're trying to jam in a lot of different inputs into one function. I highly suggest you split them into different functions instead. This keeps them predictable and easy to maintain. This will avoid cases like "Oh! I want to preserve `_`" and stuff but your function clobbers it, regardless.

In that case, CamelCase piece can be simplified to the following:

```js
function camelCaseToSpinalCase(stringToReplace) {
  return stringToReplace.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(match, offset) {
    return (offset ? '-' : '') + match;
  }).toLowerCase();
}

document.write(camelCaseToSpinalCase('TestFooBarBazClass'));
```

`replace` accepts a string or pattern to replace and a function that generates the result. In this case, we don't have parenthesized blocks so we only get `match` and `offset` and no additional args in between. In all cases, we lowercase the text. If `offset` is `0`, we're at the beginning of the text, meaning we don't add the dash before the text.

The snake-case piece into:

```js
function snakeCaseToSpinalCase(stringToReplace) {
  return stringToReplace.replace(/_/g, '-').toLowerCase();
}

document.write(snakeCaseToSpinalCase('Test_Foo_Bar_Baz_Class'));
```

Comment: Except it won't work for some variations. I should've added requirements before, sorry. Ive added example inputs that function should process correctly.